# Angular observable doesn't filter json array result

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs, observable

i'm a beginner in TypeScript and Angular so this question might some strange.
i have a simple JSON that returns a list of Heros:
http://demo8521374.mockable.io/titan

i need my service to perform GetById but why Hero always comes out undefined, can someone please point me to the right location, this is what i'm doing:

```html
        return this.http.get("http://demo8521374.mockable.io/titan").map((response: Response) => {
            var result = response.json().heroes as Hero[];
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }).filter(x => x.filter(x => x.id == id)).first().toPromise();
```

in my console i can see the array was printed but in my component is not getting the object:

```html
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap
            .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.heroService.getHero(+params.get('id')))
            .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);

        console.log(this.hero)
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified the code as follow and it worked, sure there is a better way:

```html
    getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {

        return  this.http.get("http://demo8521374.mockable.io/titan").map((response: Response) => {
            var result = response.json().heroes as Hero[];
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        })

            .map(heros => {
                let y = heros.filter(x => x.id == id)[0]
                console.log(y);
                return y;
            })
            .toPromise();
```

Comment: This _is_ a way to go. `Observable.filter()` is filtering _events_(!), not the data in the event. So, your use of `.filter()` within `.map()` is absolutely correct here.

Answer (score 0):

While `switchMap` returns a new observable, I assume the `getHero` method returns an observable as well. In that case you need to subscribe to the `getHero` observable and now the `switchMap` observable to assign to your hero property as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap
            .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.heroService.getHero(+params.get('id'))
            .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero));

        console.log(this.hero)
    }
```

Or if `getHero` is returning a promise, then it should look as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap
            .do((params: ParamMap) => this.heroService.getHero(+params.get('id'))
            .then(hero => this.hero = hero)).subscribe();

        console.log(this.hero)
    }
```

It is hard to proscribe an answer to this question though as what you are doing is a little unclear and seems to indicate that you are mixing Observables and Promises when my guess is that you only need Observables.

Update service to:

```
 return this.http.get("http://demo8521374.mockable.io/titan").map((response: Response) => {
            var result = response.json().heroes as Hero[];
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }).filter(x => x.id === id).first().toPromise();
```

Comment: thanks but this didn't help, the issue is in the service not the component, when i manually create a Hero promise and return it from the service it works.

Comment: @TomerMiz See updated answer. It looks like your filter is wrong. The predicate that you pass to the filter method will be run once for each item in the array. It seems as though you were treating each item in the array as an array itself.